# Усложнение алгоритма Кадане

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Как найти количество отрицательных чисел в подпоследовательности с максимальной суммой?

Comment: шаг1: найти подпоследовательность с максимальной суммой (легко гуглится), шаг2: посчитать кол-во отрицательных чисел в ней (просто перебрать все)

Comment: @Vladimir а без сохранения последовательности?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто немного разобраться, как работает алгоритм.

В нём же есть два условных оператора - один может обновить максимум суммы, второй обнуляет сумму, если она стала отрицательной.

Вот при срабатывании второго нужно обнулить текущий счётчик отрицательных, а при срабатывании первого занести текущий счётчик отрицательных в потенциальный ответ.

```
 if currensum > bestsum:
     bestsum = currensum
     bestneg = negativecount
```

Где этот самый счётчик обновлять, думаю, понятно.